# Do I have to run my Monero Wallet as an Administrator?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero

My Monero wallet needed to resync every time I closed it out and opened it again (Wallet blocks remaining). I discovered that running the wallet as an administrator allows the autosaving feature of the wallet to work correctly, fixing the re-syncing issue. Is the wallet designed to be run as an administrator or have I improperly configured it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the wallet file(s) is/are owned by that administrator user. It is likely you put your wallet somewhere your normal user cannot write, and so saving the wallet cache after sync fails. You probably need to either move the file somewhere your normal user can write, or change the permissions on the wallet files and/or directory the wallet file(s) are in to allow writing by that user.